# B2C OpenID Connect with Azure AD

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to connect Azure AD to B2C via open ID connect. Using a MSAL JS i am able to successfully login to Azure AD and local B2C users.

However when a user is created in B2C portal (from Azure AD) the mail fields are missing e.g. name & email

looking through the ID token from the Azure AD there are no values returned for email or name.

Comment: Are you going to portal.azure.com and then creating the user in b2c directory?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an Azure AD B2C user, e.g. federated from another Azure AD tenant to the Azure AD B2C tenant, using the Azure AD B2C portal. You must create this user using either an Azure AD B2C flow/policy or the Azure AD Graph API.

When you invite an Azure AD user from another Azure AD tenant to the Azure AD B2C tenant, they are added as a guest user, e.g. so that they can co-manage the Azure AD B2C tenant.